# Перенос значение php, которое выводится в базу

Tags: php, html, sql

Не могу понять, как перенести значение (в данном случае название товара - $item и итоговая цена - $total_price).
Эти значение выводятся из корзины в оформление заказа. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки "Подтвердить заказ" они вместе с другими значениями (фио, адрес и тд) улетали в базу.

Сразу извиняюсь возможно за дурацкий вопрос и за кривой код.

Код php:
[image: Код php]
Код страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
База:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У тебя total_price из формы не отправляется.
Вставляй результат в форму, типа так:

```
<input type="hidden" name="total_price" value={$total_price}
```

И oformzak.php полно ошибок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!